# css specifity between attribute selectors and user agent stylesheet in email design

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-email, css-specificity

I am working on a responsive email template, and wish to apply `display: block !important` to 2 `<td>` elements in order to go from 2 columns to 1 column layout. Im using the following selector:

```
td[class="mainArticleContent"], 
td[class="mainArticleImage"] { 
    display: block !important;
}
```

The thing is: these styles are not applied when i view the email in the browser (safari or chrome). They still get the user agent style: `display: table-cell;`

I thought that an attribute selector would have higher specificity than UA stylesheets?

if i instead write:

```
.mainArticleContent, 
.mainArticleImage { 
    display: block !important;
}
```

Then the style get applied, and everything works as i want it to. But i am told that this can cause issues with YAHOO mail clients, as they might always show the mobile version, and that the attribute selector would be a workaround.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem for me?

Comment: are mainArticleContent and mainArticleImage the only classes on the td elements?  Are they on the td elements?  Can we have a sample of the html you are trying to render?

Comment: @DaveBush has answered (asked) the essentials. But still, you see the mail as html page or inlined and rendered by gmail or third party?

Comment: @DaveBush You were right: I had another class on my .mainArticleContent. but the other class didn't declare another display mode ?? but it solved my problem, simply by removing the other class. Can you explain why this is? Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for a class attribute that matches exactly that string.  Since your string has something else in it, it doesn't match exactly.  to match containing, you would use

```
td[class*="mainArticleContent"], 
td[class*="mainArticleImage"] { 
    display: block !important;
}
```

See http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/

Comment: I suspect it'd be more appropriate to use `~=` than `*=` since you're matching class names (which are whitespace-delimited).